# Update the Record of Related Model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How to update a record in the related table model by chain expression?

This is what I currently do (and it works)

```
$user = User::find(1);

$token = Token::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
$token->token = $request->token;
$token->save();
```

But can I do the above in a more elegant way, such as?

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->token()->token = $new_token;
$user->token()->save();
```

**My User Model**

```
public function token()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Token');
}
```

Comment: I think your approach is pretty good

Comment: Being a nerd, I was hoping that there is more practical way of doing that

Comment: Well, you could do this as well on one line:  `User::find(1)->token()->update(['token' => $new_token]);`

Comment: I would accept it as correct answer cos I like it

Comment: I've elaborated a little bit more as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one line:

```
User::find(1)->token()->update(['token' => $new_token]);
```

Just know these things before using it:

- User find could return `null` if the user id is not found.
- The saved and updated model events will not be fired for the updated models.
- The update method execution does [not go through the Eloquent model](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_update) methods.

However in your particular case I think it's valid, specially if you know that the user id will always be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can do it like this :

```
User::find(1)->token()->update(['token' => $new_token]);
```

**Or** do it in you`App\Token` class like this :

```
User::find(1)->token()->update_token($new_token);
```

**And** create `update_token` function in `App\Token` class:

```
public function update_token(string $new_token)
{
      $this->update(['token'=>$new_token]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$user = User::with('token')->findOrFail(1);
$user->token->update(['token' => $request->token]);
```